# Escaping everything in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've got a list of commands (generated by nmake and obtained using event tracing) that I want to run. The obvious way to do this is to put them in a batch file. This works fine for simple commands, but then one of them turned out to be the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c for %I in (..\..\bin\*) do @for %J in ("%~nI.exe: $(srcdir)/bin/%~nI" "  $(ECHO) generating $(@)" "  $(Q) copy /y /b $(STUBPROGRAM) $(@) > nul" "    $(Q) echo.>>$(@)" " $(Q) echo.>>$(@)" " $(Q) copy /b $(@)+$(srcdir:/=\)\bin\%~nI $(@) > nul" "" ) do @echo.%~J>>scriptbin.mk
```

which cmd barfed on:

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~nI.exe: $(srcdir)/bin/%~nI" "        $(ECHO) generating $(@)" "      $(Q) copy /y /b $(STUBPROGRAM) $(@) > nul" "    $(Q) echo.>>$(@)" "     $(Q) echo.>>$(@)" "     $(Q) copy /b $(@)+$(srcdir:/=\)\bin\%~nI $(@) > nul" "" ) do @echo.%~J>>scriptbin.mk
```

Which I suppose shouldn't be very surprising as the act of reading commands from a batch file performs various substitutions, interpretations of special characters et cetera.

I could try to modify the stuff in the batch file by escaping things, but that would require the program that does the escaping to know everything there is to know about how cmd parses things and what needs to be escaped; I could see myself still trying to fix bugs in that this time next year.

I could write my own program to run a batch file without doing any substitutions or interpretations, but that wouldn't be as good as having batch files that can be run as-is.

Is there any way to say something like 'escape everything' or 'turn off substitutions for the rest of this file' or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to solve this problem if you run the batch file with:

```
cmd <foo.bat
```